# how to delete data from AutoCompleteTextView with adapter directly

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-adapter, autocompletetextview, android-adapterview

I have <kbd>AutoCompleteTextView</kbd> which uses to search the value from database. On Click of  filtered value it's set to the <kbd>AutoCompleteTextView</kbd> which can be use to update the value for the particular data.

I would like to incorporate delete <kbd>ImageView</kbd> functionallity next to filtered item. On Click of it Alert Dialog whether to delete or not. Been able to develop the scenario.

```
MyCursorAdapter adapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.edt_delete_item, null, fromName, to);
searchText.setAdapter(adapter);


adapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new CursorToStringConverter() {
            @Override
            public String convertToString(android.database.Cursor cursor) {
                // Get the label for this row out of the "state" column
                //final int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("state");
                int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBConstant.Patient_Name_Columns.COLUMN_NAME);
                String strName = "";
                if(index != -1)
                {
                    strName = cursor.getString(index);
                }
                return strName;
            }
        });
```

QueryFilter has been used on Custom Adapter:-

```
adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(DBConstant.Patient_Name_Columns.CONTENT_URI, null,DBConstant.Patient_Name_Columns.COLUMN_NAME_SEARCHALGO + " like '%" + SearchAlgo.getNameSearchAlgo(constraint.toString())+"%'", null, "0");
                return cursor;
            }
        });
```

Custom Adapter:-

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
  public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
}  

@Override 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  

    //get reference to the row
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    //check for odd or even to set alternate colors to the row background
    if(position % 2 == 0){  
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(238, 233, 233));
    }
    else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
    }
    return view;  
    }  
 }
```

Adapter of <kbd>AutoCompleteTextView</kbd> has  layout as below inside `edt_delete_item` having <kbd>ImageView</kbd> with delete option.

On Click of Adapter it get set in <kbd>AutoCompleteTextView</kbd> -> SearchText.

[image: What UIx looks like]

I've already handled onClick Listener of <kbd>ImageView</kbd>.

It's hard to get the `id` of the data which is feeding in the adapter.

Can i delete the data of adapter with that ImageView?

As per suggestion how one can set the Cursor ID in the tag of ImageView? As cursor throws `CursorIndexOutOfBoundException` when passing it to `MyCustomAdapter`

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from passing as the tag for the `ImageView` the id of the row from the `Cursor`(in the `getView()` method). You can then retrieve it in `onClick()` with `v.getTag()`.

Comment: @Luksprog : Where you guiding sounds perfect way to go. But I'm not getting how to set the tag from cursor to that ImageView.

Comment: In the `getView()`(or `bindView()`) method of your custom adapter retrieve the id from the `Cursor`. Set that id as a tag for the `ImageView`, `imageView.setTag(Long.valueOf(idFromCursor))`.

Comment: @Luksprog : I reached till where you guiding but still I've doubt how to pass `cursor id` to custom adapter.I'm appending my custom adapter in OP.can you show small snippet of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Luksprog `setTag` and `getTag` is the way to achieve the goal i want. Setting Tag in `getView() within <kbd>ImageView</kbd>` and getting Tag back onClick event is the right choice to perform the operation.

Changed `getView()` of CustomAdapter which extends `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Code snippet:-

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    // get reference to the row
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    // check for odd or even to set alternate colors to the row background
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edt_delete_item, null);

    getCursor().moveToPosition(position); 

    long id = getCursor().getLong(getCursor().getColumnIndex(DBConstant.Patient_Name_Columns.COLUMN_ID));

    TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtText);
    ImageView delete = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.deleteIcon);

    String strName = getCursor().getString(getCursor().getColumnIndex(DBConstant.Patient_Name_Columns.COLUMN_NAME));

    name.setText(strName);

    delete.setTag(String.valueOf(id));
    return view; 
    }
```

OnClickListener of <kbd>ImageView</kbd> Handled the delete option:-

```
  boolean d = false;
  String _id = v.getTag(); //v is the view in here i.e ImageView in my case.
  d= SmartConsultant.getApplication().getContentResolver().delete(DBConstant.Patient_Name_Columns.CONTENT_URI, "_id=?", new String[] { _id }) > 0;
  if(d)
    {
      //Show Toast Successfully deleted.
     }
```

Comment: I'm getting `NullPointerException` as Tag has not been set in `getView()` of Custom Adapter. I've used newView instead of getView but there's no such difference. Could please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @VikalpPatel Sorry, I meant the **`bindView()`** method, the `newView()` method is not called for each row. I don't know why that exception is thrown, where do you set the listener for the `ImageView`?