# How to clear AutocompleteTextView using cross symbol(right side) in android fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, autocompletetextview

I have AutocompleteTextView with cross symbol right side of AutocompleteTextView. When i touch cross symbol clear AutocompleteTextView. 
this is the code

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private AutocompleteTextView autocompleteTextViewSearch;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myhealth, container, false);
        autocompleteTextViewSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.autocompleteTextViewSearch);

        autocompleteTextViewSearch.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
                final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
                final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
                final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if (event.getX() >= (autocompleteTextViewSearch.getRight() - autocompleteTextViewSearch.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                        autocompleteTextViewSearch.setText("");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this `setOnTouchListener` is working fine in Activity, But it is not working in Fragment. i want suggestions...

Comment: add a listener to that image and perform a icon.setText("");

Comment: that cross symbol was created by drawableRight="src/cross.png" of AutocompleteTextView

Comment: Try logging the location of the drawable, and also log the location of your touch event, to check whether your touch event is actually within the bounds of the drawable.

Comment: It's working inside fragment too.

Comment: it is not working...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21114145/2826147